# How do I remove this error message in ModelForm?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a way to update an item of the database that has the fields CharField and ForeignKey. I want to pass the original values so that they don't have to be manually entered for each field every time, but this gives me a "Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices." warning for the `group` field. How do I remove this warning message?

Setting the error message (in ModelForm) to something else manually still displays an empty (unordered) list item. Setting the form in `UpdateUserView` to `form = UserForm()` gets rid of the errors, but doesn't pass default values to the form.

models.py

```py
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

forms.py

```py
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'group']
```

views.py

```py
class UpdateUserView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'update_user.html'

    def get(self, request):
        user_id = int(request.GET.get('user_id'))
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        default_name = getattr(user, 'username')
        default_group = getattr(user, 'group')
        form = UserForm({'username': default_name, 'group': default_group})
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'user': user})
```

[End Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dn6Yr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `initial` argument like this:

```
class UpdateUserView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'update_user.html'

    def get(self, request):
        user_id = int(request.GET.get('user_id'))
        user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
        form = UserForm(initial={'username': user.username, 'group': user.group.id})
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form, 'user': user})
```

Look I'm using `group: user.group.id` here, since the model Field you are referencing there in your form is a `ForeignKey`.

I hope this help.

Comment: I forgot to mention it but I had also tried this in some form before, don't know why I changed it. Works well, thank you.